# MVC: Is it possible to save data when [x] button in fancybox is clicked

Tags: model-view-controller, fancybox

I have a fancybox opened and the data is just a list of radiobuttons that the user can select a value from.

Is it possible to save the data when user selects a data from radiobuttons and then clicks on the [x] button? I am using MVC.

[image]

Comment: use the `beforeClose` callback to save your data before fancybox is closed (you may need to perform an ajax POST to save it where you want/need to)

Comment: @JFK Thank you for your feedback. Unfortunately I am new to Jquery, can you point me to a tutorial of this? It would be really helpful. Thanks!